# Delete dictionaries in iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary

Is it possible to delete installed dictionaries (some or all of them) in iOS 9.2? There are dictionaries that I need not, but they take place, and some are even duplicated. As you can see from a screenshot, there is not cross button to delete them.

[image: View on dictionary list]

Answer (score 1):

- Select a word in a safari page, then tap Look Up
  [image]
- You will find a **Manage** button on the bottom left corner
- A list with dictionaries will appear you can choose to delete (x symbol) or download new ones (cloud symbol)